# Visio 2010: replace a shape

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

In Visio 2010, how can I change the shape of a single element?

If I create a new one, I'd have to re-apply text, connections and format.

Comment: I am fairly sure there is no way to directly do this in Visio. It may be possible to come close to this feature by writing some code using Visio's VBA support - however that would be a relatively complex task. Can you explain more about why it is you need to do this? Perhaps we can find some other options that will help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I asked this question directly to the Program Manager of Visio 2010 at Microsoft during an internal MS event on campus and the answer was: "This is not possible". I have been missing this feature since Visio 2003 and hope that it will be finally added in the next version of Office.

Comment: __NOTICE__ - This is no longer the correct answer. The feature has been added

Comment: @FastAl: that is not true, the feature was NOT added to Visio 2010!

Comment: What I meant to say was they added the feature to Visio 2003 like the answerer had wished for. And now I am learning that software companies don't do that kind of thing? Darn, I need to go back to school! I guess I can't assume readers will know to look in newer versions of office...

Answer (score 16):

An update: this feature was added to Visio 2013

See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/officedevdocs/change-shapes-in-visio-2013

Comment: Thanks for the info! Oh finally! Good thingI'm already on Office 2013.

Answer (score 9):

The "Change Shape" feature was introduced in Microsoft Visio 2013. Demo:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for..

Answer (score 4):

Following is an Excerpt from here : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officedevdocs/archive/2012/08/23/change-shapes-in-visio-2013.aspx

Visio 2013 introduces a "Change Shape" feature that enables you to swap out a selected shape or group of shapes in the drawing with another type of shape. The new shapes can retain the position, connections, formatting, shape text, and/or shape data of the originals.

Note: You can only replace 2D shapes with other 2D shapes (like a Decision shape for a Process shape) and 1D shapes with other 1D shapes (replacing one type of connector with another). You cannot replace a connector with a rectangle, as an example.

Comment: Does anyone know how to use this functionality using VBA - the Shapes.ReplaceShape does not seem to handle existing connectors.